# Get category url in loop

Tags: categories, links

I need to get the category url for put it in meta snippets. Now the output inside the span is  tag with url. I need to get only the url without tag and put inside $cat_display. I try with 2 options, but i will see an error : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

```
// Get post category info
$category = get_the_category();

if(!empty($category)) {
        // Get last category post is in
        $last_category = $category[count($category) - 1];

        // Get parent any categories and create array
        $get_cat_parents = rtrim(get_category_parents($last_category->term_id, true, ','),',');
        $cat_parents = explode(',',$get_cat_parents);

        //$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
        $cat_parents_url = get_category_link($cat_parents->term_id);
        // Loop through parent categories and store in variable $cat_display
        $cat_display = '';
        foreach($cat_parents as $parents) {
                $cat_display .= '<li class="item-cat" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">'.$parents .'</span></span><meta itemprop="position" content="'. $counter++ .'" /></li>';
                $cat_display .= '<li class="separator"> ' . $separator . ' </li>';
        }

}
```

Comment: Have u try **get_term_link()** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

That's because `$cat_parents` is not an `object`; it's an `array`:

```
$cat_parents_url = get_category_link($cat_parents->term_id);
```

Secondly, to get just the category URL, call [`get_category_parents()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents) with the *second* parameter set to `false`, like so:

```
$get_cat_parents = rtrim(get_category_parents($last_category->term_id, false, ','),',');
```

`$get_cat_parents` would then be a list/`string` of category *slugs* and not category links in HTML format such as `<a href="http://example.com/category/slug">Name of the category here</a>`.

Then, in the `foreach` loop, you can get the category URL like so:

```
foreach($cat_parents as $slug) {
    $term = get_category_by_slug( $slug );
    if ( ! $term ) {
        continue;
    }

    $cat_url = esc_url( get_category_link( $term->term_id ) );
    ...
}
```

I.e. Get the category/term `object`/data using `get_category_by_slug()`, and then the category URL using `get_category_link()`.

Here's the full code I used: (re-indented for clarity)

```
// Get post category info
$category = get_the_category();

if(!empty($category)) {
    // Get last category post is in
    $last_category = $category[count($category) - 1];

    // Get parent any categories and create array
    $get_cat_parents = rtrim(get_category_parents($last_category->term_id, false, ','),',');
    $cat_parents = explode(',',$get_cat_parents);

    $cat_display = '';
    $separator = ', '; // not defined; so I defined it here.
    $counter = 0;      // not defined; so I defined it here.
    foreach($cat_parents as $slug) {
        $term = get_category_by_slug( $slug );
        if ( ! $term ) {
            continue;
        }

        $cat_url = esc_url( get_category_link( $term->term_id ) );

        $cat_display .= '<li class="item-cat" itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"><span itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">'.$cat_url .'</span></span><meta itemprop="position" content="'. $counter++ .'" /></li>';
        $cat_display .= '<li class="separator"> ' . $separator . ' </li>';
    }

    echo $cat_display; // test

}
```

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, @user3309614. =)